# Writing to JSON file from PHP fseek()/rewind() not working

Tags: php, json

I'm working on a logger class , the `JSON` that is being added has the following format

```
{"log_owner" : "test123","log_message" : "Has logged in","log_timestamp" : "1397921556","log_type" : "1"}
```

To retrieve it I require square brackets around all the different `JSON` Objects as the following :

```
[
    {"log_owner" : "test456","log_message" : "Has logged in","log_timestamp" : "1397921856","log_type" : "2"}
    {"log_owner" : "test123","log_message" : "Has logged in","log_timestamp" : "1397921556","log_type" : "1"}
]
```

I've managed to insert it at the beginning of the file whenever the file didn't existed, but the main issue resides on **moving the closing bracket to the end of the file as I'm adding new objects** , I've tried to move my file pointer 2 places before to be able to overwrite the last bracket keep adding the closing bracket to every new entry, I'm trying to accomplish this with :

```
if(!$content_new) {
$pos=ftell($handle);
fseek($handle,$pos-2);
}
fwrite($handle, $content);
fclose($handle);
```

But **seems that It does not work with `.json` files**, as I'm not able to move my file pointer to any other line or rewind it.

How could I accomplish this ? Any kind of guidance  or suggestions for improvement is highly appreciated .

Thank you.

Comment: To make the multi-line parts valid JSON, you'll also need to add commas to the end of the lines (except the last one in the array). Is there any particular reason why you need the whole file to be a single JSON array?

Comment: I'm dynamically retrieving the contents with jQuery and applying a search filter in different attributes to the entire array.

Comment: It might be easier to store the log lines as they are and use a quick PHP script to output the file as JSON, rather than fiddling with the file each time a line gets added.

Comment: Hmmm yes, indeed salathe. I managed to accomplish it by getting the contents, deleting from the full contents string and then writing again, it's not scalable and one error would throw everything down , so I guess I'll be switching to storing as they are.

Comment: I would suggest **not** trying to store them as 'json' format, use something that you can  parse easily. Convert them to 'json', on the way out, to the routine that wants them. PHP does not do 'json' that well. it is 'quirky'.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RyanVincent , I went with just plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Direct solution for your problem - quick and dirty.

```
<?php
function writeLog($path, $newLine) 
{
    $exists = file_exists($path);
    $handle = fopen($path, 'c');
    if (!$exists) {
        // first write to log file
        $line = "[" . PHP_EOL . $newLine . PHP_EOL . "]";
    } else {
        // file exists so it has one or more logged lines
        $line = "," . PHP_EOL . $newLine . PHP_EOL . "]";
        fseek($handle , -(strlen(PHP_EOL) + 1) , SEEK_END);
    }
    fwrite($handle, $line);
    fclose($handle);
}
$path = __DIR__ . '/file.json';
// delete file if exists - for tests
if (file_exists($path)) {
    unlink($path);
}
$line = '{"log_owner" : "test123","log_message" : "Has logged in","log_timestamp" : "1397921556","log_type" : "1"}';
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    writeLog($path, $line);
}
```

#### Problems

1. concurrency
2. scaling
3. JSON is not easiest to edit and view
4. no easy filtering

## Use CSV, output JSON

```
<?php
function writeLogCSV($path, $newLine) 
{
    $handle = fopen($path, 'a');
    fputcsv($handle, $newLine);
    fclose($handle);
}

function readLogCsv ($path) 
{
    $handle = fopen($path, 'r');
    $rows = [];
    while (false !== ($line = fgetcsv($handle))) {
        $rows[] = array_combine(
            ["log_owner", "log_message", "log_timestamp", "log_type"],
            $line
        );
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo json_encode($rows);
}
$path = __DIR__ . '/file.csv';
// delete file if exists - for tests
if (file_exists($path)) {
    unlink($path);
}
$line = ["test123", "Has logged in", "1397921556", "1"];
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    writeLogCSV($path, $line);
}
readLogCsv($path);
```

#### Good parts:

1. easy to read and write

#### Problems:

1. scaling
2. concurrency
3. no easy filtering

## Store your log in database or use logging service, output JSON

#### Good parts

1. no concurrency issues
2. easy filtering
3. speed
4. good for scaling